# Error while receiving data from sql server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have the following code in one class of my app that works fine. The following code snippet recieves a string "Okay" from a remote server.

```
try {
                   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", et1.getText().toString()));
                   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", et2.getText().toString()));                     
                   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                   client.execute(httppost);
                   HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                   HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

                   if (respEntity != null) {
                      // EntityUtils to get the response content
                      content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);

                    Log.d("valueeeeeeeeeeee", content);
                   }
```

The code for the php is in the following:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "admin"; 
$pass = "123";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$db_select=mysql_select_db("mydb");
if(!$db_select){
    die(mysql_error());
    echo "error";
}

    $query = "select count(1) as count_users from wp_users where user_login = '".$userid."' and user_pass='".$pass."'";   

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['count_users']>0)
    {
       echo "Okay";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Not found";
    }

if($medo=mysql_query($query)){
    header("localhost/filename");
    exit;
}else{
    echo"<p> Error</p>";
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Whereas when I try to run the following code in php it gives me an error for the same android code.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; 
$user = "admin"; 
$pass = "123";
$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die (mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."<BR>");

$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);

$db_select=mysql_select_db("mydb");
if(!$db_select){
    die(mysql_error());
    echo "error";
}

    $query= "SELECT * FROM wp_users";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if("$num_rows" > 0)
    {
       echo "$num_rows";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Not found";
    }


    if($medo=mysql_query($query)){
    header("localhost/filename");
    exit;
}else{
    echo"<p> Error</p>";
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Is there a different way to receive the number of rows or the data in rows or columns at the Android end?

Answer (score 0):

First of all change

```
if("$num_rows" > 0)
{
   echo "$num_rows";
}
```

to

```
if ($num_rows > 0)
{
   echo $num_rows;
}
```

Secondly if you just want to get number of rows use query

```
$query= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users";
```

Comment: it still gives me "NumberFormatException : Invalid Int" error

Comment: $query= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users"; <------ doesn't really help since it gives me incorrect number of rows.

Comment: @MohammadSohaib Your query is `$query= "SELECT * FROM wp_users";` therefore `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users` gives exactly what you asked in your question - number of rows in the result set. Either change your query or clearly explain exactly what rows you're trying to get number of.